# Mongoose: not saving this.property using methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with mongoose. I try to set two properties using Schema methods but they won't save at all.

**User Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const crypto = require("crypto");

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  salt: String
});

UserSchema.methods.passwordHash = password => {
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
  this.password = crypto
    .pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, "sha512")
    .toString("hex");
};

...

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

I took the *passwordHash* method from [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/)

**Index.js**

```
const User = require("../../models/User");

...

const newUser = new User();
newUser.email = email;
newUser.passwordHash(password);
newUser.save(err => {
    if (err) return res.send({ message: "Server error" });        
});
```

All I get is:

[image: MongoDB Compass screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - I used the arrow function so *this* refers to the original context not the current model:

```
UserSchema.methods.passwordHash = function(password) {
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
  this.password = crypto
    .pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, "sha512")
    .toString("hex");
};
```